# Using N3000 Intel FPGA as smart NIC

Tags: intel-fpga, dpdk

Is it possible to use N3000 Intel FPGA Network accelerator card as Smart NIC ?
if yes can somebody share the details ?
We would want to use it as Smart NIC using dpdk based poll mode driver

Comment: @vjoysula are there any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Programming FPGA with DPDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875872/programming-fpga-with-dpdk/62906815#62906815). Hence the right way is to check with Intel network builder for sample code for RTL images for N3000 having ACL, Tunnel termination and others.