# Programming FPGA with DPDK

Tags: network-programming, fpga, dpdk

I'm facing a problem: there is a need to create a simple firewall to cut unwanted packets directly on FPGA. Basically the idea is to have a shared table with rules. This table is meant to be accessed from FPGA to check whether to pass a packet or not and it's populated by an app from userspace.

I've heard of DPDK project that can handle packet processing. But I couldn't find any info how to make it work on FPGA. Is it possible? Are there any recommendations on solving the problem?

Comment: do you have the RTL image for Frierwall on the FPGA. If yes, as per my current understanding you can use DPDK IFPGA driver to manage the same `https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-18.05/rawdevs/ifpga_rawdev.html`. more details in https://www.dpdk.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/35/2018/09/Rosen-Xu-FPGA-Acceleration-and-Virtualization-Technology-in-DPDK.pdf.

Comment: To be honest I'm not familiar with how it works. I mean I'm a bit aware of how to write simple opencl code for FPGA. But I have no idea how DPDK works and I didn't find anything that looked like kernels from opencl. A piece of source code would help

Comment: as shared from my end, DPDK does not have any Firewall RTL images. If you have a firewall RTL image (inline or lookaside) you can access the FPGA for sending, receiving and managing via DPDK.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK libraries does not pack any RTL images as reference code. In the current case, there are no firewall RTL images either in inline or lookaside mode.

A couple of FPGA variant which uses inline FPGA with Ethernet are Intel `N3000` which houses Intel `Arria 10` and `Fortville X710` and Intel `Arkville Data Mover`. Link to talk in DPDK summit of the same is https://www.dpdk.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/35/2018/12/PetrKastovsky-AcceleratingDPDKviaP4-programmableFPGA-basedSmartNICs.pdf, and https://www.bittware.com/fpga/arkville/ . While DPDK `IFPGA RAW` PMD allows managing and RX-TX packets out from the device. Links https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-18.05/rawdevs/ifpga_rawdev.html.

hence the expectation of having DPDK to create FPGA RTL image for Firewall and program the FPGA in use is not true.

note: One can add themselves to Netwrok Builder program from Intel and get couple sample references (RTL images) which are used for similar use case like ACL firewall.